# How to represent values that can be of more that one type in Apache Thrift?

Tags: thrift

Is it possible at all to use Thrift to represent something like the Java type Map where the value in the Map is known to be e.g. either String or Integer?

In other words, is there any way to represent values where the actual base type is only known at run time but guaranteed to be one of a set of types which is known in advance.

Is there an alternative for high performance serialisation which can do this?

I am currently using JSON with a manual implementation of the necessary code in Java and Python, but it would be nice to solve this in a more orderly fashion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thrift requires you to specify a type. That type can be a structured type like a `struct` or a `union`, however it has to be a type:

```
union Anything {
  1: string s
  2: i64    i
  3: double d
}

service foo {
   Anything  bar(1: Anything anyArg)
}
```

However, if you plan to use JSON and just wrap that JSON data into a Thrift message somehow, then maybe you want to go with `string`. On the other hand, if you only exchange such JSON strings like in

```
service foo {
   string  bar(1: string json)
}
```

then to some extent this would raise the question whether Thrift is the right tool for the job. It may still be, but you are responsible for the JSON serialization/deserialization yourself ...